Add a widget in the tabBar
I am making the booking and orders page and I want to create a container with a shadow in my Products tab . This is what I have right now and this is what I want to obtain: 
Here it's the code , should I do a widget? because if I add container I get a red line under .( also this happened with a SizedBox) Same I want to the orders tab .
class BookingOrdersScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const BookingOrdersScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<BookingOrdersScreen> createState() => _BookingOrdersScreenState();
}

class _BookingOrdersScreenState extends State<BookingOrdersScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map>>? stream;
  late String currentUserID;
  TabController? tabController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
    currentUserID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 193, 59),
          title: SizedBox(
            width: 140,
            height: 140,
  
          ),
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
              bottom: Radius.circular(30),
            ),
          ),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /
                  1.5, // change it on your need
              child: DefaultTabController(
                length: 2,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    TabBar(
                      tabs: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.calendar_month,
                            color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 59, 161),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.shopping_basket,
                            color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 59, 161),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TabBarView(
                        controller: tabController,
                        children: const [
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 135,
                            width: 100,
                          ),
                          Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'No orders made',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


To create a container with a shadow in your Products tab, you can use a Container widget. The red line usually indicates a problem with the code or an unresolved issue. Let's address that and show how to add a shadow to the container.
Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
child: Container(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  color: Colors.white,
  boxShadow: [
    BoxShadow(
      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
      spreadRadius: 2,
      blurRadius: 5,
      offset: Offset(0, 3),
    ),
  ],
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
),
child: Column(
  children: [
    Text(
      'Product 1',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    ),
    // Add more widgets for your product here
  ],
),),),


https://imgur.com/a/rjDB9mg
